# Loading fixtures on production, wrong parameters

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Based on [Environment specific data fixtures with Symfony+Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817971/environment-specific-data-fixtures-with-symfonydoctrine) I changed `php app/console doc:fix:load -n` for `php app/console doc:fix:load -n --env=prod` so it recognizes a environment even though it's called from the console and all of the sudden it doesnt recognize the database parameters anymore (`root@localhost` is not the user/pass configured in `parameters.yml`, the only place where those appear is `parameters.yml.dist`, which shouldnt be relevant). The code is production ready and it works in production, databases connections and all, it has been for months, but the fixture command *doesn't*.

[image: Putty output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*parameters.yml.dist* is used only when a composer update or install is done and generates the according *parameters.yml* file after relative questions been asked (using bundle incenteev composer parameter handler).

If default database values is used from the dist file only in prod environment, I would suggest two things after deleting *parameters.yml* file :

**1.** Redo a composer update and answering db related questions again to regenerate parameters file

**2.** Clear cache for dev/prod environment.

And try again.

I hope this helps, and if not, let me know any further changes.

Best Regards.

Comment: The parameters.yml is built, the assets installed, the cache cleared. **The site is working**. Everything does work (not just in dev, through app_dev.php) in the production environment.... except this command. :/

Comment: Re-run your command after doing a

app/console --env=prod cache:clear

did not changed anything ?

Comment: Now it works. That's weird, cache:clear should have executed before, it's part of the script. And the site DID load, which means prod parameters where correctly configured. I don't know, maybe just the weekend passed. Sometimes, stuff solves itself.... which is something *really scary*...

Comment: Glad it worked. Lot of weird things appear very often with Symfony related to cache. Manually erase cache/* content folder usually correct a lot of problems. Feel free to ask anything if any other problem is encountered. Regards.